# Transforming angular directive template when using isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing a custom directive to produce a dropdown element. If I use isolated scope, the compile function does not transform the template.

Mostly I am changing ng-options on the select element as they are provided in the directive. How would I achieve the same with isolated scope?

```
myApp.directive('helloWorld', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      id:'@',
      label:'@'
    },
    template: '<div class="control-group">' +
                '   <label for="{{id}}" class="control-label">{{label}}</label>' +
                '   <div class="controls">' +
                '       <select id="{{id}}" class="medium m-wrap">' +
                '       </select>' +
                '   </div>' +
                '</div>',
  },
  compile:function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude){
   var opts = tAttrs.textField 
    ?'item.' + tAttrs.textField + (tAttrs.groupBy ? ' group by item.' + tAttrs.groupBy : '') + ' for item in ' + tAttrs.itemSource
    :'item for item in ' + tAttrs.itemSource;

    tElement.find('select').attr('ng-options',opts);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `{{label}}` does not exist on the isolated scope. You can solve this by passing a reference to the parent scope to the isolated scope inside your directive:

```
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       replace: true,
       scope: {
           id:'@',
           label:'@'
       },
       // in the directive!
       controller : function($scope){
           $scope.label = $scope.$parent.label;
       }
```

However this is not an advisable paradigm. As it means that the only data your directive can listen for is 'named'. So its better to use an attribute, (which is looks like you are doing). So...

```
 // in the directive!
 controller : function($scope, $attrs){
    $scope.$parent.$watch($attrs.itemSource, function(itemSource){
        $scope.itemSource = itemSource;
    });
 }
```

something along those lines.

Comment: I added as you suggested in the controller, but still it wont work

Comment: No, it the directive!

Comment: Are you copying and pasting my code? Or looking at the concept and learning? Because I have no way of understanding your implementation to a depth were I am going to understand everything that needs to be bound to the isolated scope.